# Need help setting up Contentful headless cms with Nextjs 13 using the new app directory

Tags: reactjs, contentful, next.js13, headless-cms

I am currently teaching myself how to fetch content in NextJs 13 using the new app directory instead of the old pages directory. I am building a mock recipe app that will pull data from Contentful. The traditional method is to use the pages directory utilizing the getStaticProps() method. That is no longer supported in the app directory. The app directory supports the fetch api. Can someone help me set this up properly.

Here is my current code in the main page.tsx file

```
import { createClient } from 'contentful';

const client = createClient({
  space: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID as string, 
  accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_KEY as string, 
});

async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/${process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID}/entries?access_token=${process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_KEY}&content_type=recipe`
  );

  return res.json()
}


export default async function Recipes() {
const data = await getData();
console.log(data)
  return (
    <div className='recipe-list'>
      Recipe List
    </div>
  )
}
```

I'm not even sure if I need createClient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `createClient` with the new fetch API.

First of all your page.tsx needs to be under `/app/recipes/page.tsx` if you want the route for the recipes to be `www.yourdomain.com/recipes`.

And then try this code in your `page.tsx` to see if you get what you want. Otherwise I need more information as to what is not working as expected.

```html
async function getRecipes() {
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/${process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID}/entries?access_token=${process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_KEY}&content_type=recipe`
  );

  return res.json()
}


export default async function Recipes() {
const recipes = await getRecipes();

  return (
    <ul>
      {recipes.map((recipe) => (
        <li key={recipe.id}>{recipe.name}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

make sure to change `recipe.id` and `recipe.name` to whatever fields you have created in Contentful.

Please run the local development server and then go to `localhost:3001/recipes` to see if it works.

Comment: Thank you Emin. I had to play around with the objects in the array to get the map to work, but that was the solution. It was under recipe.fields.title and recipe.sys.id etc. I changed the folder structure like you suggested. I was able to get it to display on the page.

Comment: Awesome, glad you made it work! Sorry for the confusion, I am using the GraphQL API which sends data without the `fields` subroute, I should have noticd that you are using REST